# Ramda filter if not match

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to filter all elements that don't match a condition. I was able to get this to work:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
function notSame(x,y) {
  R.pipe(
    R.equals,
    R.not
  )
}

R.filter(
  R.pipe(
    R.equals(1),
    R.not),
  a
) // [2,3]
```

But I feel like there has to be a simpler approach :)

Comment: Why not http://ramdajs.com/0.20.1/docs/#reject

Comment: Also there is "complement" function to make predicate function reversed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[R.reject](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reject) is what you're after:

```
var isOdd = (n) => n % 2 === 1;
R.reject(isOdd, [1, 2, 3, 4]); //=> [2, 4]
R.reject(isOdd, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {b: 2, d: 4}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thanks